# is the size of a picture in MB is whats used in memory? or is it a different number?

Tags: android, memory, drawable

In my android app, the drawable folder has a total size of 1.1 MB (28 compressed pictures)

is that the MAX amount of memory that will be used by my pictures, or is it calculated differently?

thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is that the MAX amount of memory that will be used by my pictures

No.

> is it calculated differently?

Yes. Generally speaking, each image will consume 4 bytes of heap space per pixel, based on the image's resolution. IOW, you are calculating things based on the size of compressed images (PNG, JPEG) on disk. What matters is their size in memory.

The calculations also depend upon whether a given drawable is used as-is, or whether is is down-sampled or up-sampled based on a density conversion. For example, if you have a 512x512 image in `res/drawable-mdpi/` named `foo.png`, and you load `R.drawable.foo` on an `-xhdpi` device, and there is no other version of `foo.png` (e.g., in `res/drawable-xhdpi/`), then Android will up-sample your 512x512 image so that it is the same on-screen size on the `-xhdpi` device. That will turn the image into a 1024x1024 image, quadrupling the heap space usage.